# Php go to URL depending on HTML form

Tags: php, html, url, twitter

Hi i would like to make a page that would ask a user some text to tweet on twitter  then setting the retunred text to a value then going the url https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=$url

the value $url would store the info from the HTML form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple form like this:

```
<?php

if($_POST['text']) {
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $url = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=$text";
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
?>
<html>
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Post to Twitter</button>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use php to create this url. The $url is a variable that would include the string of the form data.

```
<?php 
    echo "<a href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" . $url . "'></a>";
?>
```